# Restore a backup and keep apps saved on SD

Tags: 8.1, apps, backup, micro-sd

I have to bring my own personal phone in assistance for a not-working button and I need to back up.
*<sub>(I do not know why, to my girlfriend, who took the same model for the exact same problem, they have formatted the phone)</sub>*

On my phone, I have some application still under development containing important data and I am concerned because I don't know how this apps might react to a backup, these apps are not recorded in the store and I can't risk losing this data.

I thought that I can move all the applications on SD card (which I'll keep) and then back up the phone, so that the restore will be faster *(I think)*.

**My question is**: If I move in this way, in the backup then there will be the needed informations to make run the applications (Store applications and my own applications) on the SD card?

**Note**: I just started learning  WP development so I'm not so good at developing.

**OS version**: 8.10.14219.341 **Phone**: NOKIA Lumia 520

Answer (score 1):

Every application you install on SD Card on windows phone device from store or under development app, that stores minor data in Phone memory like app tiles,tile titles, app title, etc. (minor data will not appear in "Files" app).

So if you backup the app you installed from store or you installed from PC(Under development apps), Those all you need to install again in order to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Apps installed on the SDcard may not work after restoring an backup. This may be due to the reasons that Nirav Madariya stated. However it had worked for me sometimes.

But considering the situation that you have valuble and non-recoveable data in those apps it is best to have them in the phone itself. It you want to free up some space on the phone for the backup move other apps whose data can be recovered or not important. Some of these can be Facebook (all your data will be in cloud), RedBus, Flipkart, etc...